# Get AccessToken using signpost OAuth without opening a browser (Two legged Oauth)

Tags: android, oauth, android-networking, signpost, android-embedded-api

I am using `signpost for OAuth` to access data from a Magento server. I have read various tutorials on the same and I reach to the point where we open a browser so that user can enter his credentials. However, as per my requirement I have to **automate** this part.

Hence, user should not get the browser page. I have this set-up done on the server side (**Magento**), where I hit the URL and get returned to the call back page. I would like to do the same through my program in Android.

I have tried the below,

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(KEY, Secret);
provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(OAUTH_INIT_URL,ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTHORIZE_URL);                
try {
    provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
    Log.d("Tokens" , consumer.getToken() + " -- " + consumer.getTokenSecret());
    }
```

and I get the request tokens. But I dont know how to bypass the next step. I tried directly accessing the AccessToken (stupid of me)  `provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, "myCallback://callback");` but no luck, it ends up in

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server   replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
```

I would really appreciate any help, as I am stuck on this from last 3 days. Please tell me if I need to provide any more data.

Comment: hi atul, did you find any solution on this?? i am also facing the same issue. I have to use oauth for webservice and dont want to open browser.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up using Rest API's from Magento. Lets see if we get any help. I will also check my last work.

Comment: If the user will not go to browser page how will he provide his credentials to magento server?

Comment: hey atul and @NiravBhandari found some solution??

Comment: @pushpendra - No bro, had to switch to REST api's eventually

Comment: yes i found it. in my case my server is not returning access token to me. what my client role is to only sign request with counsymer and secret key thats it.  so i did it and my problem get resolved.

Comment: @pushpendra: see my answer. by this way i resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

```
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(myconsumerkey,
               mysecretkey);

        HttpURLConnection request;
        URL  baseUrl = new URL(myurl);
        request = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();
        consumer.sign(request);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    request.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }
         String serverResponse = out.toString();
```